# Java Array Queues

Tags: java, queue

When creating 2 Queues like this:

```
    ArrayQueue q1 = new ArrayQueue();
    ArrayQueue q2 = new ArrayQueue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        q1.enqueue(new Integer(i));
    }
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        q2.enqueue(new Integer(i));
    }
    System.out.println("q1: " + q1);
    System.out.println("q2: " + q2);
```

It outputs: `q1: 4,3,2,1,0` and `q2: 9,8,7,6,5`.

I need a method that merges Queue `q2` into Queue `q1` with interleaved elements.
So if `println`'d again would output: `q1: 0,5,1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9` and `q2: 9,8,7,6,5`.

My class contains all the appropriate methods `enqueue`, `dequeue`, `peek`, `isEmpty`, `size`, `doubleSize`... my method name is:

```
    public void mergedQs(ArrayQueue q) {
    }
```

Basically i want to add objects to two queues, then **merge** the second queue into the first(not just add them).
Ideally i want to avoid casting them or using an ArrayList as i want them to remain Queues.

Comment: I would suggest you use the ConcurrentLikedDeque. Here is the API for it [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html). If you already have a class with methods like enqueue, dequeue etc, you can wrap the ConcurrentLinkedDeque into your class and use it as your main data structure for storing our objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find this useful. It merges any number of queues.

```
public static <T> Queue<T> mergeQs(Queue<T> ... qs) {
    Queue<T> ret = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>();
    boolean more;
    do {
        more = false;
        for (Queue<T> q : qs) 
            if (!q.isEmpty()) {
                ret.add(q.remove());
                more = true;
            }
    } while(more);
    return ret;
}
```